# Including Cocoa.h results in 9646 errors in my project

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

OS X 10.6.8
XCode 3.2.6

A C++ Carbon Project where I want to include Cocoa.h just for NSLog to debug some problems I am having.

I add Cocoa Framework to my project and I `#include <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` in my precompiled header and I get 9646 errors starting with ObjC Runtime stuff.

What have I done wrong?

Update: Some errors:

NSObjCRuntime.h:

/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:60:0
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:60:
error: expected unqualified-id before '@' token

/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:62:0
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:62:
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*'
token

/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:63:0
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:63:
error: 'NSString' was not declared in this scope

/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:63:0
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:63:
error: 'aSelectorName' was not declared in this scope

/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:64:0
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:64:
error: 'NSString' was not declared in this scope

/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:64:0
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:64:
error: 'aClassName' was not declared in this scope

/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:65:0
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:65:
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*'
token

Comment: please post some errors with your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are encountering a problem where some files are treated as pure C/C++ and are not supposed to have Obj C code in them. The solution is to change XCode properties for project and say treat C/C++ files with Obj C or some wording like that.